# Use tuples/lists as array indices (Python)

Tags: python, matrix

Assume I have an n-dimensional matrix in Python represented as lists of lists. I want to be able to use an n-tuple to index into the matrix. Is this possible? How?

Thank you!

Comment: if you're thinking of it as a matrix, you may(probably) want to be using numpy.

Comment: @roippi: you're right, i do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
matrx = [ [1,2,3], [4,5,6] ]

def LookupByTuple(tupl):
    answer = matrx
    for i in tupl:
        answer = answer[i]
    return answer

print LookupByTuple( (1,2) )
```

Comment: using `*tupl` in the "def" line you can call with `1, 2` directly, i.e., `print LookupByTuple(1, 2)`

Answer (score 9):

Using

```
>>> matrix = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

You can do:

```
>>> array_ = numpy.asarray(matrix)
>>> array_[(1,2)]
6
```

Or without numpy:

```
>>> position = (1,2)
>>> matrix[position[0]][position[1]]
6
```

Comment: `numpy` is really the way to go when dealing with matrices.

Answer (score 3):

For fun:

```
>>> get = lambda i,m: m if not i else get(i[1:], m[i[0]])

>>> matrix = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
>>> idx = (1,2)
>>> get(idx, matrix)
6
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes

```
>>> from functools import reduce # Needed in Python 3
>>>
>>> # A 3D matrix
>>> m = [
...       [
...         [1, 2, 3],
...         [4, 5, 6]
...       ],
...       [
...         [-1, -2, -3],
...         [-4, -5, -6]
...       ]
...     ]
>>>
>>> m[0][1][2]
6
>>> tuple_idx = (0, 1, 2)
>>> reduce(lambda mat, idx: mat[idx], tuple_idx, m)
6
```

Or you can create a class Matrix in which you have a `__getitem__` method (assuming the lists of lists is inside self.data):

```
class Matrix(object):
    # ... many other things here ...
    def __getitem__(self, *args):
        return reduce(lambda mat, idx: mat[idx], args, self.data)
```

With that method you can use `minstance[0, 1, 2]` if `minstance` is a Matrix instance.

[Numpy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html) `ndarray` already has something like that, but allowing slices and assignments.

Answer (score 0):

If your code guarantees that each index in the tuple corresponds to a different "level" of the matrix, then you can just index each sublist directly.

```
indices = (12, 500, 60, 54)
val =  matrixes[indices[0]][indices[1]][indices[2]][indices[3]]
```